# Cálculos com números após a vírgula e toFixed

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando toFixed em um programinha que fiz pra calcular um desconto aqui no meu trabalho, porem eu não consigo calcular se uso números decimais! Se eu coloco 150.50 por exemplo, o programa interpreta e me retorna o resultado de 150 inteiro, sempre...

```
var valorDoAbastecimento = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor do abastecimento")) ;

var totalDeLitrosAbastecido = valorDoAbastecimento / 3.09

var descontoPorLitro = 0.10 ;

var totalDesconto = totalDeLitrosAbastecido * descontoPorLitro ;

var dinheiroPago = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor pago em dinheiro."));

var valorTotalComDesconto = valorDoAbastecimento - totalDesconto

var troco = dinheiroPago - valorTotalComDesconto;



mostra ("<b>O total de litros abastecido é de: </b><mark><ins>" + totalDeLitrosAbastecido.toFixed(2) + " Litros") ;
mostra ("</mark><b></ins>O valor do desconto nesta compra é de </b><mark><ins>" + totalDesconto.toFixed(2) + " R$");
mostra ("<b></mark></ins>O Valor total da compra com o desconto fica:</b> " + "<mark><ins>" + valorTotalComDesconto.toFixed(2) + " R$")
mostra ("</mark></ins><b>O troco do cliente é de </b><mark><ins>" + troco.toFixed(2) + " R$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando um `parseInt()`, ele irá converter o valor para Inteiro. Para converter o valor em um Float utilize `parseFloat()`. Mas lembrando que o número deverá ser digitado com . (ponto) como separador dos centavos.

Comment: consegui cara!!

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é que você está fazendo `parseInt()`, porém gostaria de te avisa que existe um método chamado `toLocaleString()`.

**Sobre o** `Number​.prototype​.toLocale​String()`

> O método `toLocaleString()` retorna uma string com uma representação sensível a linguagem deste número.
>
> Os novos argumentos `locales` e `options` permitem às aplicações especificar a linguagem cujas convenções de formatações serão utilizadas e personalizar o comportamento da função. Nas implementações anteriores, que ignorava os argumentos `locales` e `options arguments`, a localização utilizada e a forma de retornar a string eram totalmente dependente da implementação.

**Exemplo básico**

```
var numero = 123456.789;

// informando um formato de moeda
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
// → 123.456,79 €

// o yen japonês não tem uma unidade menor
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }))
// → ￥123,457

// limitando a três dígitos significativos
console.log(numero.toLocaleString('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }));
// → 1,23,000
```

**Leia mais sobre este assunto** [neste link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).